# How to select Text from the lookup field after searching particular text in robot framework selenium

Tags: selenium, search, input, robotframework

I need to select the text entered in a search field. The following robot framework selenium keyword are passed.

Run Keyword And Continue On Failure  Input Text  xpath: //input[@type='search']  610-Page

Run Keyword And Continue On Failure  Execute JavaScript  document.getElementsByClassName('input-group').value =  "610-Page";

but when I check the value of the selected field then the output is empty.

Run Keyword And Continue On Failure  Element Should Contain  xpath: //input[@type='search']  610-Page

Error I get:
Element 'xpath: //input[@type='search']' should have contained text '610-Page' but its text was ''

Comment: Can you share the entire script?

Comment: If you know what text you are inputting, why checking the field? And why `... Continue on Failure`? Probably it failed when you input the text, so the field is empty.

Comment: You need to select the text as the title says - literally make it selected / highlighted, or retrieve the text that has been typed in it? These are two different things.

Comment: Is there a keyword that I can select or highlight the input text?

Comment: @Angela Is your use case similar to google search where after entering the search term and hitting enter, you want to retrieve value (your text) from the search field?

Comment: Yes, the search action is similiar to google search. After entering the text, the web browser (firefox) gives a list of options to select from. I need to retrieve the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Input element won't have text, it will have the value keyword. So if you want to get the text value which is there in the input box then you will have to get the value attribute.